# "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" before fetching data from the server

Tags: angular

I have my `html`

```
<input name="name" [(ngModel)]="address.name" matInput >
```

and my `ts` like so

```
  public address: Address;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAddress(1).subscribe(address => {          
      this.address = address;
    });
  }
```

and my interface looks like

```
export interface Address {
  ...
  name: string;
}
```

When I'm trying to populate the input I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I know this happens because the `address` object is null until it gets populated in the subscribe method. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You could use `*ngIf` to create the element when `address` exists

Answer (score 1):

Initialize to empty Object as follows,

```
public address = new Address();
```

or use *ngIf in the template (dirty),

```
<input name="name" *ngIf="address" [(ngModel)]="address.name" matInput >
```

and is
`export class Address {...}`

Comment: Error: Initializer type {} is not assignable to variable type Address

Comment: you need to initialize to that type

Comment: How can I achieve the first approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider this, try using `any` as an optional type and then assign `{}` to `address`:

```
public address: (Address | any) = {};
```